# What is the purpose of SET NULL in Delete/Update Foreign Keys constraints?

Tags: foreign-key, null

I am probably being narrow minded, but if I create a foreign key constraint and a row gets updated or deleted, I lose that connection if the child table's column gets set to NULL.

What is the purpose of intentionally keeping these orphaned rows?

Comment: I'm looking for use-cases, and I don't think they're database-specific (might be wrong here)

Comment: I have never seen a use-case for this either...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whether `set null` is useful or not depends on what you have chosen `null` to mean in the particular context - with all the confusion and opinion around `null` IMO the sensible approach is for the DBA to

1. Choose (and document) what it means for each nullable field
2. Make sure it means ***one*** thing only

With those rules, consider the following use case:

- You have a table 'shop' (eg individual premises)
- You have a table 'retailer' (eg chains)
- The 'shop' table has a lookup field referring to the key of 'retailer'
- You have defined `null` to represent an independent shop (ie one that is  not part of a chain)
- A 'retailer' closes branches to the point that you consider its shops to be independent

In this case, an `on delete set null` makes sense. There are other ways of modelling these business rules but this is the simplest and if it accurately fits the facts that you care about in the real world, I suggest it is perfectly ok

Comment: Good points with a strict meaning of null, and with your example it's clear why this is a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the use cases I can think of generally are of the form "Well, we could do something different but we felt like doing this instead".

Consider an `owner` field for a bug in an issue tracking system at a company.  If John quits, surely all his problems should not simply be deleted when his account is removed.  Even then, some databases allow `SET DEFAULT` as an action (or having a trigger perform the same task), and having a `Nobody` employee be the default owner of issues could be an option.  Or we could have a `disabled` field for John rather than deleting his record.

Comment: In this case I would argue not to allow deletes (`RESTRICT`), if for no other reason that to point the blame to an old employee when something goes wrong with it!