# To NULL or not to NULL?

Tags: null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why shouldn't we allow NULLs?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls)

I've heard that it's a bad idea to do database design such that nullable fields exist. However, eliminating nullables often cause much more complex schemas.

Given a schema where elimination of the NULL is considerably more complex (e.g. replace any instance of NULLs with a separate table which gets JOIN'd), or using a nullable field, which is the better action, and why?

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls.

Comment: Looks like a bit of a duplicate, as far as I see it :-).

Comment: I'm backing the community on this one. I did speak to the [programmers.se] mods tho at the time of migration, and agreed that it should be migrated. This gives the members of [programmers.se] a link to the final answer tho ;)