# Normalization of library book table with multiple authors

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, database-design

I have a database structure with two tables:

- The first one is called `Author`, has two columns (`AuthID`, `AuthName`) and its `Primary Key` is (`PK_AuthID`).
- The second one is called `Book` and has three columns (`BookID`, `BookTitle`, `AuthID`). Its `Primary Key` is (`PK_BookID`), and has (`FK_AuthID`) defined as a `Foreign Key` that referes to `Author` table.

The question is: If one `Book` has more than one `Author`, what is the best design pattern to follow in order to maintain the second `Author`, and at the same time keep the `Book` table without `NULL` values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only sensible design I can think of - since books can have 20 authors - is to always use a junction table and don't bother storing the AuthorID in the book table *some of the time* (and don't even *think* about storing a comma-separated list of AuthorIDs, please, or adding `Author2`, `Author3`, ... columns). This will just make queries complex.

```
BookAuthors(BookID (FK points to Book), AuthorID (FK points to Author))
```

In this case, you can remove the AuthID column from the Book table. Don't bother abbreviating to AuthID - you don't really think that makes you more productive or makes the code easier to read, do you?

Also, as a general rule, [don't spend time trying to worry about how you will eliminate NULLs everywhere](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5222/1186).

Comment: I was trying my best to avoid using nulls, as the database will be used to store relatively large data that will be accessed online, I don't want it to slow down for any reason (nulls) is one of that reasons.

Comment: @Ashraf Where did you get the idea that NULLs slow things down?

Comment: I learned it from a programmer who teaches database programming.

Comment: @Ashraf Maybe you should consider other opinions or, you know, *proving* that it slows anything down.

Comment: He told me that he did an experiment, and proven that it slows database performance.

Comment: @Ashraf You know a NULL in a database once set my dog on fire.

Answer (score -1):

AuthID does not belong in the Book table at all because a book can have more than one author. My suggestion:

```
Author (AuthID*, AuthName)
Book (BookID*, BookTitle)
BookAuthor (BookID*,AuthID*)
```

*=key attributes(s).

No nulls required.

Comment: Hm, but that's just what the other answer suggests. What is your point in repeating the same suggestion?

Comment: I agree but I didn't quite understand your concern about nulls so I wanted to emphasize the point that no nulls are needed.

Comment: All right. I didn't make any point in this thread apart from my previous comment, but that's okay. :) Of course, you could just post a comment under the other answer to point out this aspect to the OP, but fine. Personally I'm not in the habit of downvoting duplicate answers, but some people might be (just FYI).