# How can I create 3 tables with references On SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I started using SQL Server recently and I think this is simple to resolve.

I need to create one table with a country list, and two tables that will use the country list in a column.  Here is the code:

**1** - (uf to log a country list)

```
CREATE TABLE uf
(
id int primary key,
uf varchar(2), (dont know if can I use a column with the same name of the table)
);
```

**2** - the resumed table that will use the list.

```
CREATE TABLE carta
(
id int primary key,
uf varchar(2) not null,
);
```

**3** - the resumed table that will use the list.

```
CREATE TABLE cliente
(
id int primary key,
uf varchar(2) not null,
);
```

**I'm really thankful if someone helps me**

If have some errors in the writing, I'm sorry, I'm from Brazil and don't know English very well

Comment: Why would you ever have a `varchar(2)`? How often will this contain 0 or 1 character? Should probably be `char(2)` unless you have an unchangeable app that will barf on trailing spaces. Also, please [always specify the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Answer (score 3):

I've re-written your `CREATE TABLE` statements like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.uf
(
    uf_id INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_uf
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , uf_name VARCHAR(50) -- you *can* name a column the same as the table
                         -- but try not to, since it will result in confusion
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.carta
(
    carta_id INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_carta
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , uf_id INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_carta_uf
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES
        dbo.uf(uf_id)
    , carta_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.cliente
(
    cliente_id INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_cliente
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , uf_id INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_cliente_uf
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES
        dbo.uf(uf_id)
    , cliente_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Always specify the "schema" of the table; in the above example that is `dbo` - which is the default schema.  Specifying the schema name removes confusion about what schema will contain the table.  I've renamed the `uf` column in the `uf` table to `uf_name` to remove confusion when the `uf` table is used in queries.  You *can* name a column the same name as the table it appears in, but I would try not to do that.

The `dbo.uf` table has a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint which enforces uniqueness and makes the contents of the referenced column valid for use as a [foreign key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in other, related tables.

The `dbo.carta` and `dbo.cliente` tables have `FOREIGN KEY` references to the `dbo.uf` table.  This prevents inserting rows into those tables without a valid entry in the `dbo.uf` table.  This is commonly referred to as referential integrity and is an important principle in good database design.

I've made all the columns `NOT NULL` since non-null values are [easier to understand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls), especially when learning.

Below, we're inserting data into the three tables in a way that shows how the foreign keys work.  First, we'll insert two country names into the `dbo.uf` table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.uf(uf_id, uf_name)
VALUES (1, 'Brazil')
    , (2, 'Canada');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.uf;
```

The results:

[image]

The `uf_id` column is used in the other two tables, instead of the actual name of the country itself:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.carta (carta_id, uf_id, carta_name)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Natal') --Brazil
    , (2, 1, 'Fortaleza') --Brazil, again
    , (3, 2, 'Winnipeg'); --Canada

SELECT *
FROM dbo.carta;
```

[image]

```
INSERT INTO dbo.cliente (cliente_id, uf_id, cliente_name)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Paulo') --Brazil
    , (2, 2, 'Nedja') --Canada
    , (3, 2, 'Max'); --Canada, again

SELECT *
FROM dbo.cliente;
```

[image]

To join the three tables together, you use the `JOIN` clause, such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.uf
    LEFT JOIN dbo.carta ON uf.uf_id = carta.uf_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.cliente ON uf.uf_id = cliente.uf_id
```

which shows the following results:

[image]

Steve Stedman made a fantastic poster about the different kinds of `JOIN` statements, which is available [here](http://stevestedman.com/2015/05/tsql-join-types-poster-version-4-1/).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is a [FOREIGN KEY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx).  This enforces referential integrity between two tables.  In other words in your case cliente.uf can never have a value in it that doesn't exist in uf.uf (yes a column can be named the same as a table).  Here is the code for your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE uf
(
id int primary key,
uf varchar(2), 
);

-- Column(s) must have a unique index to be referenced by a foreign key
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_uf ON uf(uf);

CREATE TABLE carta
(
id int primary key,
uf varchar(2) not null CONSTRAINT fk_carta_uf FOREIGN KEY (uf) REFERENCES uf(uf)
);

CREATE TABLE cliente
(
id int primary key,
uf varchar(2) not null CONSTRAINT fk_cliente_uf FOREIGN KEY (uf) REFERENCES uf(uf)
);
```

Note that there MUST be a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the column(s) referenced by a foreign key.

Comment: I'm really thankfull, thank your time to answer Kenneth

Comment: There must be a UNIQUE index **or** a UNIQUE constraint. (or a PRIMARY KEY constraint, if we want to be really pedantic)

Comment: Please, look my comment bellow here

Comment: You won't see the tables on object explorer until it is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

The first block of code runs in SQL 2012 as

```
CREATE TABLE uf
(
id int primary key,
uf varchar(2) NOT NULL 
);
```

`Not Null` was added to prevent multiple null entries
Insert code to fill the table:

```
insert into uf values (1,'CT')
insert into uf values (2,'VT')
insert into uf values (3,'CA')
insert into uf values (4,'DC')
```

A foreign key relation prevents updates or inserts of values into the other two tables that are not in the first one.

```
ALTER TABLE carta 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_uf FOREIGN KEY (UF) 
    REFERENCES uf (uf) ;
```