# How to correctly define foreign keys to heterogenous dimensions in fact table?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

### Question

**What is the best practice for defining foreign keys in a fact table to multiple different and mutually-exclusive dimension tables?**

### Example Case

#### Business process

I am creating a dimensional model for the business process of **inventory movements**. These inventory movements can be triggered by three different actions:

- orders
- returns
- internal transfers

#### Fact / dimensions

I'd like to foreign key to the three 'actions' above that already have corresponding dimensions within our warehouse:

```
dim_orders
dim_returns
dim_internal_transfers
```

My current plan is to create a foreign key column for each of these, understanding that only 1/3 of them will join "properly", like so.

```
# fact_inventory_movements

_key products                abc
quantity                     10
occurred_at                  2020-01-01

_key_orders                  null/placeholder
_key_returns                 null/placeholder
_key_internal_transfers      12345
```

*I'm concerned that this prevalence of mostly-null or placeholder foreign keys has a 'smell' to it that may be improved by a better design.*

I've consulted both the Data Warehouse Toolkit and Star Schema: The Complete Reference, but am having difficulty finding an equivalent example. I'd love to be pointed to a specific chapter that explicitly spells this out!

Comment: [Related](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/why-shouldnt-we-allow-nulls). Are you willing/able to rethink your dimensions?

Comment: @mustaccio thanks for the link! and sure, though they're definitely relevant concepts that already exist and join to other stars. I imagine there might be a more "core" dimension that encompasses orders, returns, and internal transfers that would be appropriate here, but i wonder if that's just shifting the burden of abstraction to the dimension (which might be the right move!).

Comment: Do your 3 dimensions have a lot of different columns or are they similar? It would help if you could share their structures?