# Add an auto now field to an existing table

Tags: database-design, date

I want to add a new column `created_datetime`. This column will automatically be filled with a the current date/time value when inserting a new row.

How should I handle the value for existing rows. Leave null? or set a default?

Comment: That depends on your use case. Do you want there to always be a value? Are you able to backfill the `created_datetime` or is setting it to the minimum `datetime` value sufficient? Otherwise, leaving them `null` will consume less space on the table but probably a negligible amount unless your table has millions+ of records in it.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of `NULL` is sometimes interpreted differently, but generally speaking it is the value used to symbolize "unknown".

Using a magical token/placeholder value (such as 1900-1-1) is generally an anti-pattern and bad habit. It might be an obvious placeholder in some cases (ex, event times for a system created in the 21st century), but for other cases it might be less obvious (dates of birth for historical figures).

Your use case is the perfect example of when you **should** allow `NULL` values in your database. [This other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5227/52344) addresses usage of `NULL` is much more detail.

I'd suggest adding the new column as null-able, populating the `CreateDate` when that value is known (ie, new rows), and leaving it `NULL` when the value is unknown (ie, existing rows)