# How to use RESTRICT for Foreign Key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key

In the database structure of

```
  CREATE TABLE Country (
  name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE City (
  name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE Map (
  country varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  city varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (country,city),
  FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES Country (name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (city) REFERENCES City (name) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I expect to delete parent from `City` by leaving the corresponding value in child intact by these three equal commands

```
  FOREIGN KEY (city) REFERENCES City (name) ON DELETE NO ACTION
  FOREIGN KEY (city) REFERENCES City (name) ON DELETE RESTRICT
  FOREIGN KEY (city) REFERENCES City (name)
```

But when using `NO ACTION` OR `RESTRICT` or omitting `ON DELETE`. MySQL does not allow me to delete from parent column with this error:

```
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
('test'.'Map', CONSTRAINT 'Map_ibfk_2' FOREIGN KEY ('city') REFERENCES 'City'('name')
 ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Where am I wrong? Isn't it the responsibility of the SQL's `NO ACTION` to delete the parent and leave the child orphan?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [MySQL Documentation on DELETE RESTRICT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

> • RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table.
>   Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON
>   DELETE or ON UPDATE clause.

As for NO ACTION

> • NO ACTION: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to
>   RESTRICT. InnoDB rejects the delete or update operation for the parent
>   table if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table.
>   Some database systems have deferred checks, and NO ACTION is a
>   deferred check. In MySQL, foreign key constraints are checked
>   immediately, so NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT.

DELETE RESTRICT protects the parent from deletion, not the children.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.

Answer (score 5):

If you are wanting to delete the parent and leave the child, then you're probably wanting the [`ON DELETE SET NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) option:

> SET NULL: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and set the foreign key column or columns in the child table to NULL. Both ON DELETE SET NULL and ON UPDATE SET NULL clauses are supported.
>
> If you specify a SET NULL action, make sure that you have not declared the columns in the child table as NOT NULL.

There's a lot of 'not' in that last sentence, so just make sure the parent_id **can** be NULL.

See also this related qestion: [What is the purpose of SET NULL in Delete/Update Foreign Keys constraints?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5176/what-is-the-purpose-of-set-null-in-delete-update-foreign-keys-constraints)

By defining a foreign key, you've told the database to not accept entries in the child table that do not have a corresponding value in the parent.